# Change starting point row

Tags: excel, vba

Have a form I'm trying to modify based on the amount of inputs on another worksheet.  Can't get the code below to work.  I am a VBA novice, so it's probably something simple.  Not sure my "Dim" and "Set" commands are correct as I'm getting an "Object Required" error for 'startrow1'.

Code should add a variable number of rows (which it does).  But problem is the starting point. The 'default' start point would be "A20", but that needs to change based on a number of rows previously added above it with another macro. (ws1.Range.("D45").value).
So if "D45" is 2, the start point should change to "A22".

```
Sub Addquotedrows()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim ws1     As Worksheet
Dim ws2     As Worksheet
Dim addquoted As Range
Dim startrow As Range
Dim startrow1 As Range


Set ws1 = Sheets("Input")
Set ws2 = Sheets("PakEmail")
Set addquoted = ws1.Range("D46")
Set startrow = ws2.Range("a20")

Set startrow1 = startrow + ws1.Range("D45").Value

Let X = 0
Do While X < addquoted

With ws2
    startrow1.EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlUp
End With

X = X + 1
Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Offset the *startrow* by the number of rows in D45.

```
Set startrow = ws2.Range("a20").offset(ws1.Range("D45").Value, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

With the code you have, you would need to set startrow to an integer, then do the add, and set your range of startrow1 = to those values like this:

```
Dim startrow Integer
Set startrow = 20
Set startrow1 = Range("A" & startrow + 
ws1.Range("D45").Value
```

Your issue was that you were adding an integer to a range, much like being in the middle of a large city and saying you are looking for address 9.
The error message was saying, "Ok, 9 what?"
Does that make sense?

So now you have 2 options.
1) use the addresses as mentioned above with offset
2) use numbers as presented here.
Either one should work for what you want, just depends upon your style, what makes sense to you, and if there is other code that could stumble if you use one way over the other.  (very low chance of that, but still a possibility).

Good luck!